# What is this ferrite-like thing on this diode's leg?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

A switching power-supply module from Mean-Well was making this clicking-noise when turning it upside down, so I opened it to take a look.

I discovered this ferrite-like thing on one leg of this diode. It is loose and I have no idea what it is doing there. What is its purpose?

[image: thing on power-supply diode]

Answer (score 1):

It is usually intended to either: absorb EMF emissions from the device OR attenuate high frequency noise in current traveling though that component.

Comment: And unless it's an absolute counterfeit, it really is a ferrite bead, not a "ferrite like thing".  AFAIK, they're usually made out of some material that has high mu and lots of loss at high frequencies, but to some extent placeing ferrite beads to good effect is cut-and-try: the solution that worked on your last circuit may make this circuit's emissions even worse.

Comment: Thanks for your replies! Would it be a bad idea to glue it down with some hot glue or silicone in order to prevent it from making noise/vibrating?

Comment: No, that is not be a problem if the hot glue melts above the temp of the diode.  You don't want it melting all over the place.

Comment: yeah, silicone glue would be a better choice than hot-melt. use a neutral-cure type (not acetic).  epoxy glue is another alternative. cyanoacrylate could work too.

Answer (score 0):

Ferrite beads are able to dampen parasitic oscillation and thus prevent them. They put a resistance against high frequency currents.

[w2aew explains the use of ferrite beads very well.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=81C4IfONt3o&t=621s)